# Best pathfinding algorithm for traversing a 2D array (grid) touching some mandatory points (JavaScript/Java/C# )

Tags: c#, java, javascript, path-finding, dijkstra

I have a 2D array which I want to traverse starting form one point and ending to another with the following constraints:

- Only moves in horizontal and vertical direction are allowed
- The path must touch every mandatory point inside the array
- the array has no obstacles

Here is a graphic representation:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | E |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| S | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Starting from point S, the algorithm should be able to find the shortest path to get to E, touching all points rapresnted with "1" and moving only horizontally or vertically.

I have to implement it in Javascript (but even in C# or Java should be good, I think I could translate it :) )

Which algorithm could best suit my needs?
I've googled a lot but found only some Dijkstra or A star implementations which are similar but different (they dont't have to touch the mandatory points...)

Have someone experienced such a problem?

Could someone help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is S and E are fixed ? Like S is bottom left and E is top right ? Like S and E will be always opposite corners ?

Comment: No, they are not fixed, but they are always on the border columns and opposite each other, I mean if S is in the leftmost column E is in the rightmost, and viceversa. But if you have a solution for opposite corners feel free to share it :)

Comment: Did you consider using a backtracking algorithm?

Comment: Thanks Gamb, I don't know backtracking algorithms at all, do you know where can I find some examples?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Sorry for late reply. I think you might have got some implementation. If not, think about this.

Let me do a little simple version of this first. Lets assume that S and E are either top-most or bottom-most in their respective columns. The problem picture in question fits this.

The algorithm should :

1. Move up ( down) the column until you reach the max of( current column top,next column top ).
2. Transition to the next column. Next column become the current column.
3. Move down the column until you reach the max of  ( current column bottom, next column bottom)

Things to consider

1. You can run the algorithm on rows.
2. Last row/column needs to handle differently.
3. Last row/column and first row/column might need traversed twice.
4. Need to modify if the S and E are middle of the row/column.

P.S. I remember doing this algorithm problem somewhere. Will post the source if I find somewhere.